# Splitting Rows in a data frame and saving to a new data set

Tags: r, dataframe

The question is: Split the rows of clean_mlb into a training set consisting of 29 rows for the non- Pittsburgh teams and a testing set of one observation corresponding to the Pittsburgh Pirates. Save these dataframes as train set and test set.

clean_mlb is a dataframe that was made from a data set called mlb

[image: Data Set MLB]

[image: Data Frame clean_mlb]

This is my code:

```
  if(mlb$TM[i] == "PIT"){
    
  }else{

  }
}
```

I wasn't sure what to put after the if or else or if this is even what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data.  It's hard to provide good examples in solutions if there's no actual example data to work with.  Post `dput(mlb)` or even a sample of `mlb` that contains a few examples of `TM == "PIT"` and its complement.

Answer (score 0):

You can `subset` your data based on value in `TM` column.

```
train <- subset(mlb, TM != "PIT")
test <- subset(mlb, TM == "PIT")
```